# How to Add Margin to Relative Div Overflowing Parent to Move Content Down

Tags: html, css, overflow, clearfix

I have created a div that overlaps its parent, and the margins after the div are not behaving as expected. I *expect* the content following the div to appear *after* the overlowing div, but it's not.

**Expected Behavior** :

[expected_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W95Re.png)

**Reality** :

[reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQFpy.png)

---

Here is the **code**:

**HTML**:

```html
<div>
  <div class="hero">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1>Greg Potts' Website</h1>
      <h4>
        Software Developer / Vim-er / Bash-er
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Some content next</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
.hero {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #272c33;
}
.heading {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(15vh);
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: auto; /* horizontally center */
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.heading h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { text-align: center; }
```

I suspect it has something to do with clearfix, but have tried a few solutions and they haven't worked as intended.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with restructuring the HTML element in order to achieve this, as it is can not be done without adding blank clearfix element if working with the structure your set.

Instead it would be really simple to un-nest the `.heading` from the `.hero` elements and use negative value for the `top` css property instead.

You can additionally wrap the `.hero` and `.heading` elements in a container to adapt the bottom margin left as a result of a negative `top` value.

The code would look like the following:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="hero-container">
        <div class="hero"></div>
        <div class="heading">
            <h1>Greg Potts' Website</h1>
            <h4>
                Software Developer / Vim-er / Bash-er
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>Some content next</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero {
    height: 20vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #272c33;
}
.heading {
    position: relative;
    top: calc(-10vh);
    width: 50%;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: auto; /* horizontally center */
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.hero-container {
    margin-bottom: calc(-10vh);
}
.heading h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! Благодарам!